# Append a value to a Data Extension Field

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, mobileconnect, sms

I am trying to send SMS messages to phone numbers in MobileConnect. I need to add a "1" in front of the existing mobile numbers that I have in a Data Extension, to adhere to the proper syntax MobileConnect requires.

Can I add a statement to my SQL query Automation Activity that populates the DE being used to import contacts into Mobile Connect?

Comment: In your sql make use of the sql functions CONCAT (and cast). A slightly different example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13358923/sql-query-to-prepend-prefix-to-existing-value-in-a-field

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sure can!  Using the sql function CAST to first turn the numbers into VarChar, then you combine them together (via +) and then as the field type is number it will automatically put it back into a number format.

See below for a sample:

```
SELECT CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(mobileNumber AS VARCHAR(10)) as mobileNumber
FROM yourDE
```

Comment: Is this the Query That I would write? 
SELECT
FirstName,
LastName,
Email,
Phone,
FROM Lead_Salesforce
SELECT CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(Phone AS VARCHAR(10)) as Mobile Number
FROM Lead_Salesforce

Comment: I don't believe so. It is hard to read from comments, but I think that is malformed with 2 SELECT statements.  Try something like: `SELECT CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(1)) + CAST(Phone AS VARCHAR(10)) as [Mobile Number], FirstName, LastName, Email FROM Lead_Salesforce`