# Append a value to a Data Extension Field using SQL

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql, automationstudio

I tried to follow the example used in this [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/234205/append-a-value-to-a-data-extension-field), but I'm having trouble getting it to work. I get an err msg (Error saving the Query field.An unmatched parenthesis occurs in the query.). for Mobileconnect to work for SMS I need to append a 1 in front of the number.

```
SELECT CAST('1' AS VARCHAR(1)) 
+ CAST([Event:Who:Lead:MobilePhone] 
AS VARCHAR(10)) 
AS [Event:Who:Lead:MobilePhone] 
FROM
[SC_TEST2_LEADS_Booking_Reminder]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `CONVERT` ([my comparision vs `CAST`](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/sql/sfmc-sql-conversion-functions)):

```sql
SELECT 
    CONCAT('1', CONVERT(VARCHAR, el.MobilePhone))
FROM [EventLead] el
```

Query Studio has problems with `CAST` in `SELECT`.

Comment: thx much this works with some tweaking to add required columns. Now, if I run this in the Automation studio multiple times of course this keeps adding 1's.. Any suggestions on how I can only update each record once?

Comment: add a column "phoneUpdated" to your de. in the same query set it to true and add a condition `WHERE phoneUpdated != true`. that way the first execution sets the true marker and all following executions pass on the record.

Comment: Or, if you have clean MobilePhone data and you are sure there won't be any values starting with 1 before the change, you can use check what is the first character of your MobilePhone. If you can make such an assertion, it will let you not extend your tables.

Comment: Thank you both for your suggestions. I've attempted to do the phoneUpdated first but I'm having trouble with the set phoneUpdate == 'true' in my syntax. Here's what I have for the updatePhone:<CODE> SELECT [Event:Id],[Event:Who:Lead:Id], CONCAT('1', CONVERT(VARCHAR, el.[Event:Who:Lead:MobilePhone])) as [Event:Who:Lead:MobilePhone],CONVERT(el.[phoneUpdated],'true') as [phoneUpdated]
FROM [SC LEADS Journey - 20201201 - 2021-02-24T111741157] el
WHERE phoneUpdated != 'true'</CODE>

Comment: Just use `'true' AS [phoneUpdated]` - no need to convert.

Comment: I tried `code ,'true' as [phoneUpdated] ` but the new record did not append the 1 and the phoneupdated did not ad the true. Maybe I'm missing something.:

`code SELECT [Event:Id],[Event:Who:Lead:Id], CONCAT('1', CONVERT(VARCHAR, el.[Event:Who:Lead:MobilePhone])) as [Event:Who:Lead:MobilePhone],'true' as [phoneUpdated]
FROM [SC LEADS Journey - 20201201 - 2021-02-24T111741157] el
WHERE phoneUpdated != 'true'`

Comment: Have you tried this code in Query Studio? Does it output correct vales there?

Comment: Query Studio shows it as an error Error saving the Query field.Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: Try running it twice. Query Studio has a known bug, where the first query run returns an error that you have encountered in the past, regardless of what is in the current query. Just because.

If the second query run will also output this error, check whether your naming is correct.

I just run this query on my instance (with my field labels) and it was running correctly.

Comment: Tried a few times and the same result. Do I need to make two separate queries one to append 1 and one to add the true bolean?

Comment: No, it is not necessary. And running just twice should be enough (the bug impacts only the first run).
Can you try to create the same query using some built-in source? 
If you are using the Mobile Studio, for example:
`SELECT _MobileID AS MobileID, CONCAT('1', CONVERT(VARCHAR, _MobileNumber)) AS MobileNumber, 'true' AS PhoneUpdated FROM _MobileAddress WHERE _IsHonorDST != 'true'`
Does it also return an error for you?

Comment: when I just paste your code into query studio it works and displays the records. How do I tweak my code to work with the built-in-source, please and thank you

Comment: As the logic between two scripts is the same, play with aliases for your field labels and make sure all names are correct. Also check whether you have any tabs in the code - there shouldn’t be any (only spaces).

Comment: if I change the [Event:ID] to EventID then it runs in Query Studio. But because this is being imported from Sales Cloud the field needs to rename as Event:ID. Is there another way to include a field like this without using the square brackets?

Comment: Maybe aliasing will solve it for you - `SELECT [Event:ID] AS EventId`

Comment: Tried that too. No luck. It makes no sense why it's doing that, I don't get it.

Comment: Out of curiosity, I tried in anyways in Automation studio, and that workED. I also noticed that my phoneUpdate boolean data type did not have a default. So I also set the default as False. So between the syntax tweaks and that. I have it working now. Thanks so much. One quick question, please. How can I add a 2nd where clause for where Event:CreatedDate <= YESTERDAY

Comment: Just use AND + DATEADD/DATEDIFF ([my docs covering those functions](https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/sql/sfmc-sql-date-functions#datediff))

Comment: read the doc on the weekend a couple of times. I'm not able to wrap my head around the syntax for for getting Event:CreatedDate <= YESTERDAY

Comment: to get contacts that have Event:CreatedDate within the last day, try `WHERE DATEDIFF(DAY, [Event:CreatedDate], GETDATE()) <= 1`. If you want to be more specific (exact 24 hours, without rounding), change it to `WHERE DATEDIFF(HOUR, [Event:CreatedDate], GETDATE()) <= 24`

Comment: perfect, thank you for all your help on this much appreciated :)